# Displaying list of array in drop down in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have array populated with elements and I want to display elements of that array in drop down list.

Here is relevant piece of code.

```
 Party[] Parties = party.getAllParties;
```

In my jsp page, i have

```
 <td nowrap>
    <select label="Party List" array="Parties" name="Party List">
        <option value=<%= (Parties) %>></option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Now when i go and check view source of jsp page, i have

```
<td nowrap>
  <select label="Party List" array="Parties" name="Party List">
     <option value=[Lcom.areil.pdo.party.Party;@1404de3></option>
  </select>
</td>
```

I know, way option value is set is not correct and am not sure what is right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is because you are trying to display array directly.

The statement you have is equal to `System.out.println(Parties);`

You need to loop through the array and display each element by index like `parties[i]`.

Example:

```
for(int i=0;i<Parties.length;i++) 
{ %> 
<tr><td><%=Parties[i]%></td></tr><% 
}
```

Comment: dump question, how would you surround it with option value tag, my limited knowledge of HTML is hinderance here.

Comment: <option value='<%=Parties[i]%>'><%=Parties[i]%></option>

Comment: @Nambari-How can i get set selected value in request object so on i can retrieve selected value from drop down list back.

Comment: @Rachel: I would suggest post a new question with updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code:

```
<c:forEach var="party" items="${Parties}">
    <option value="${party}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to perform the [JSTL forEach](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/jsp/jstl-forEach.jspx) statement into your `JSP` and to output your values with the [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html). Try to use as less code of scriptlets as you can, the EL was design to replace scriplets.

Include this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

into your JSP to be able to use `JSTL`. So the code of your proper JSP should look like this:

```
<td>
    <select label="Party List" array="Parties" name="Party List">
        <c:forEach var="party" items="${Parties}">
            <option value="${party}">
                <c:out value="${party}"/>
            </option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select name="party"> 
    <option value="">SELECT</option> 
    <% for(int i=0;i<Parties.size();i++){ 
        String party= (String)Parties.get(i); %> 
        <option value="<%=party%>" > <%=party%> 
        </option>
    <%}%> 
</select>
```